# How to use multiple static mains?

Tags: java

Trying to make a program that can use sumDigits, reverse, and isPalindrome.  I need to call them from the main and test them.  I'm told to use public static int sumDigits(int n), public static int reverse(int number) and public static boolean isPalindrome(int number).  I'm just having trouble getting all three programs to run together.  Also not sure how to print the answer of the three.  Any and all help would be appreciated.  Honestly all I'm able to do right now is sumDigits x.x.  I am so confused.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter an integer");
int n = input.nextInt();
int sum = sumDigits(n);
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
System.out.println("The reverse is " + n);
}

public static int sumDigits(long n) {
int num = (int)(n);
int sum = 0;

while (num > 0) {

sum += num % 10;
num = num / 10;

}
return sum;
}
public static int reverse(int number) {
int reverse = 0;
int rem = 0;
while (number != 0) {
rem = number % 10;
reverse = (reverse * 10) + rem;
number = number / 10;
}
return reverse;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
int reverse = reverse(number);
if(reverse == number) {
return true;
}
else 
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Put them all inside your main method. Your whole program is only your main method, so everything that is supposed to happen has to be inside it.

Comment: You really should read about Java basics. There is plenty of tutorials online.

Comment: Tried  looking online and at tutorials, but haven't found out how to put 3 static's into the main.

Comment: I think your mental model of how this works is slightly off. When you run your java program, the main() method is executed. You've declared 3 other methods in your program (sumDigits, reverse, and isPalindrome). If you want your program to actually run these methods when you run the program, you need to call these methods from inside your main method. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I believe I did that right for sumDigits, but I'm unable to get it to work for reverse or isPalindrome :c

Comment: convert your integers to StringBuilder and then do looping to reverse and also determine if it isPalindrome() but every number is palidrome? when you reverse it it will automatically be a palindrome because a palindrome is a word,that is when reverse still have the same meaning

Comment: As a side note to the answer i posted below, a palindrome, is not something you check that way, it is something that is read the same from left as it is from right example "12321" [Palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome), this is besides the question here though, therefore just a side note in teh comments, i'll add in some basics on it to the answer

Comment: @BobBarker Added an answer for how static/non-static works, as well as how to do palindrome and why this is the case

Comment: @BobBarker Remember if the answer is what you were looking for, marking as answer helps others find solutions to their similar problems, if there is still issues or it's hard to understand comment, and i'll try and help better it

Answer (score 0):

to call those 3 methods use there names for main main method for example inside your main method:

```
public static void main(String arg[]){

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter an integer");
   int n = input.nextInt();
   int sum = sumDigits(n); //here is were the your first method is called
   System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
   System.out.println("The reverse is " + n);

  int returnValue = reverse(5); //here is your second method call
  boolean rValue = isPalindrome(5); //here is your third method is called
}
```

i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Java has Static and non-static methods and variables

Static are

- defined before runtime
- if in a class, it's shared between all instances
- usually used for utility functions, and constants

non-static are

- not defnineable before run-time, and need to be instantiated
- what we would call "normal" methods, used by a single class instance

Now in your case since all are static they can be called from a static context (such as a main), without first instantiating a class

Here is some example code on using static and non-static methods

```
public class Util{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Util.method1("static"); // calls on the utils static method and prints "static"
        String s = Util.method2("static2"); // calls the method, and gets the string back
        System.out.println(s); // writes out the string it got back
        Util util = new Util(); // instantiates Util class to call non static methods
        util.method3(); // prints "not static", notice this is a call on the instance not the class

        System.out.println(isPalindrome(12321));
        System.out.println(Util.isPalindrome(123321));
        System.out.println(Util.isPalindrome(123456));
        System.out.println(util.isPalindrome(82218615));
        System.out.println(util.isPalindrome(0));
        System.out.println(util.isPalindrome(-12321));
        System.out.println(Util.isPalindrome(-123321));
        System.out.println(isPalindrome(-123456));
        System.out.println(util.isPalindrome(-82218615));
        // notice how a static can be acced in 3 ways
        // defined in this class, so no need to define where it's from.
        // call it on the class it's from, by calling on the class that contains it
        // call on an instance of the class that contains it
    }
    public static void method1(String input){
        System.out.println(input); // prints input
    }

    public static String method2(String input){
        return input; // just for the example, normally useless
    }

    public void method3(){ // notice not static
        System.out.println("not static");
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int in){ // checks if palindrome
        String input = Integer.toString(in); // String of the input
        StringBuilder sr = new StringBuilder(); // StringBuilder to reverse one side
        if(input.charAt(0) == ('-')) // remove - from negative numbers assuming that is still supposed to pass the test
            input = input.substring(1, input.length());
        String left; // left side
        String right; // right side

        if(input.length() % 2 == 0){ // even lengths
            left = input.substring(0, input.length()/2); // adds in whole left side to left string
            right = sr.append(input.substring(input.length()/2, input.length())).reverse().toString();// adds in whole right side to right string
            // note that the function above used the reverse on the string side
        }
        else { // odd lengths
            left = input.substring(0, input.length()/2);// adds in whole left side to left string
            right = sr.append(input.substring(input.length()/2+1, input.length()).toString()).reverse().toString();// adds in whole right side to right string
            // note that the function above used the reverse on the string side
        }
        return right.equals(left);// returns if true or false (palindrome or not based on if right == left after reversed one side)
    }
}
```

this produces this output (from the main method)

> static
>
> static2
>
> not static
>
> true
>
> true
>
> false
>
> false
>
> true
>
> true
>
> true
>
> false
>
> false

**Extra** *Added code above*

how to check isPalindrome
In theory palindromes are things such as "12321" that is read the same both ways, thus checking them requires 2 things,

- first check if the length is uneven, if so, ignore middle, else split evenly in 2
- secondly, reverse one of the sides, and then compare if the sides are equal

Finally note that OOP, values data encapsulation, and data integrity, this is why normally a class handles it's own data and only offer static methods as utility